# redis-lua returns nil on require

Tags: lua, redis

I am a newbie to lua. I want to access redis from Lua. I've downloaded https://github.com/nrk/redis-lua, changed folder to /src, where I can see file redis.lua. So if I launch Lua and try to import this file, i get the following:

```
root@debian:/home/debian/redis-lua-master/src# ls
redis.lua
root@debian:/home/debian/redis-lua-master/src# lua
Lua 5.3.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local r = require 'redis'
> r
nil
```

My goal is to run this sample:

```
local redis = require 'redis'
local client = redis.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379)
local response = client:ping()
```

But it fails because redis variable is nil. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, you might want to compare lua redis libraries: https://github.com/daurnimator/lredis#why-not-_________

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this just means, that the library is not installed (or not in the correct place). If you are working with a dpkg-based linux-distribution, chances are good that

```
apt-get install lua-redis
```

will fix this.

Edit: I just saw that you are executing this in the Lua console. Don't use local variables there, since these are local to the scope, they will not survive to the next call.

```
redis = require 'redis'
client = redis.connect('127.0.0.1', 6379)
response = client:ping()
```

In a normal program it should work however

Comment: Dear @Ctx, thanx a lot, I have tiny progress!! But before I accept your answer, please give me some small advice. Is it possible to 'install' lua-redis without apt-get? What does it mean to install library in the world of lua? Thanx!

Comment: Perhaps you should check first, if the library is really not available (e.g. what does "return require 'redis'" in the lua-console say? Please type exactly as specified)? I am asking because usually your interpreter should give a warning/error if a require fails

Comment: require 'redis' gives table with hex address. But this is because I my current folder is src I believe. What is right approach if I am outside src folder?

Comment: No, I think the library is correctly in place then. You should try if your three commands (require/connect/ping) work when not prefixed with "local" in your lua-console

Comment: Connect crashes because socket library is missing. But my question is a bit different yet: How to install lua-redis without apt-get if I have its source files?

Comment: Usually this is just a .lua-file installed in a special directory, in the case of Debian for example: /usr/share/lua/5.2/redis.lua. If native code is used, a DLL is installed and the installation directory might differ, for example:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/zip.so